# Celery chunks tasks never Retry

Tags: python, celery

Have following chunked tasks

```
update_matching_product.chunks(update_matching_products, 10).apply_async(priority=5)
```

When inside `update_matching_product` raise `self.retry()` the chunked task never retry. Instead of that shows  `Task can be retried`

If we open celery code we see:

```
  if request.called_directly:
    # raises orig stack if PyErr_Occurred,
    # and augments with exc' if that argument is defined.
    raise_with_context(exc or Retry('Task can be retried', None))
```

So question - why chanked tasks called_directly, and how to retry failed chunked tasks?

PS: Celery is not in task_always_eager mode

Comment: Do you have result backend?

Comment: @DejanLekic yes, redis. Chord tasks work and able to retry